# What does this definition of permutation mean?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A simple question.

They give the definition of permutation as

> "a one to one mapping of the set onto the set of positive integers $\{1, 2,3,4, \ldots n\}$."

What does this definition exactly mean??

Thank you...

Comment: Kind of an incomplete definition, as "the set" is not defined.    Should be the same set...$\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.  Do you know what "one to one" and "onto" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this as mapping a set of "things" to their respective positions.

For example, I will consider the set to be $$S = \{A, B, C\}$$

However, the idea of a set has no notion of order. Hence, I can write statements like

$$
S = \{ A, B, C \} = \{B, C, A\} = \ldots
$$

So, we need to be able to formalise an idea of "order". One way to do this is to map every element of the set $S$ to some unique number $i \in [1, |S|] \in \mathbb{Z}$ (where $|S|$ is the size of the set).

So, in this case, if we wish to represent the permutation $(A, C, B)$ (notice the rounded brackets and not the curly brackets), we can use a function

$$P : S \to {1, 2, 3} \\
P (A) = 1\\
P(B) = 3 \\
P(C) = 2
$$

This tells us that $A$ is at position $1$, $C$ is at position $2$ and $B$ is at position $3$.

We need to lay down some restrictions on this function, to eliminate weird things like this:

$$
Q : S \to {1, 2, 3} \\
Q(A) = 1 \\
Q(B) = 1 \\
Q(C) = 1
$$

This is nonsense since we can't have all three of them occupy the same position! Hence, for every number $i \in [1, n]$, we need a unique $s \in S$. This tells us that the function must be *one-one*.

Since both $S$ and the set $[1, |S|]$ have the same cardinality, any one-one function between them is guaranteed to be onto. Hence, any mapping $$F: S \to [1, |S|]$$

is guaranteed to be invertible.

That's why we say that any permutation is the same as an invertible / "bijective" mapping from the set to the set of positive integers $[1, 2, \ldots n]$

Comment: Thanks, can we have some definition like this to combinations

Comment: We can define combinations, but not in terms of a functions. You can define $nCk$ as k-sized subsets of the powerset of the set $S = {1, 2, \ldots n}$

Answer (score 0):

It means a permutation can be considered as a function that maps the elements of the set $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,\ldots,n \right\}$ to itself in such a way that every number appears **exactly once** as an image.

This means you can think of a permutation as a reordering; for example, in the case of $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \right\}$, one possible permutation is:
$$\begin{array}{c}
 1 \mapsto 4 \\
 2 \mapsto 5 \\
 3 \mapsto 1 \\
 4 \mapsto 3 \\
 5 \mapsto 2 \\
\end{array}$$
In total there are $5! = 120$ of these possible permutations. You can easily see this as there are 5 possible choices for the image of 1, then there are 4 possible numbers left as the image of 2, etc. In general there are $n!$ permutations of $\left\{ 1,2,3,4,\ldots,n \right\}$.