# What's π(i) in a communication network?

Tags: graph-theory

I was reading [a text about communication networks](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap06.pdf), and they define something called $π(i)$ like this:

> We will specify the desired destinations of the packets by a permutation of $0, 1, . . . , N-1$. So a permutation, $π$, defines a *routing problem*: get a packet that starts at input $i$ to output  $π(i)$ for $0 \leq i < N$. A *routing* $P$ that *solves* a routing problem $π(i)$ is a set of paths from each input to its specified output. That is, $P$ is a set of paths, $P_i$, for $i = 0, ..., N-1$, where $P_i$ goes from input $i$ to output $π(i)$.

I don't exactly get what they mean with $π(i)$. I only heard $π$ so far in context of geometry. So I want to send something from $i$ to $π(i)$, but is $π$ here some kind of function? Is there any reason why they chose $π$ and not, say, $j$ or something? It's also mentioned it's a permutation. Permutation of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A permutation of the numbers $0,\dots,N$ is (by definition) a bijective function from the set $\{ 0, \dots, N \}$ to itself.

So yes, $\pi$ is a function, and the choice of name is perhaps because $\pi$ is the Greek letter P as in permutation.

Comment: Ah I see. So $\pi$  represents a routing, this part I got. But given a 2D-array network, what do the numbers represent? For example, in a 3x3 2D array, I have 3 inputs $0, 1, 2$ and 3 outputs $0, 1, 2$. A permutation $\pi$  would be $2, 1, 0$ for example? But what does it mean? Is it the id of the nodes I need to visit?

Comment: As it says: “get a packet that starts at input $i$ to output $\pi(i)$”. In your example, you have $\pi(0)=2$, $\pi(1)=1$, $\pi(2)=0$.

Comment: Some similar questions which might help clarify: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782221/what-does-this-definition-of-permutation-mean/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534612/definition-of-permutation.

Comment: Thank you, those are pointers I can use to continue learnig about the problem.